# IdentityServer3 Token Validation - Exception in EmitCorsResponseHeaders after insufficient scope in access token

Tags: access-token, identityserver3, bearer-token

I've set up a basic WebApi project according to the guide here https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/jsGettingStarted.html

Token validation works just fine if I pass the correct api scope in the token, but if it is not included (if the user denies access) then it proceeds to add a 403 to the response as expected.

In EmitCorsResponseHeaders (ScopeRequirementMiddleware.cs) it goes to add CORS headers but throws an exception -

```
[ArgumentException: The key 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is already present in the dictionary.]
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.Add(String key, String[] value) +178
IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.ScopeRequirementMiddleware.EmitCorsResponseHeaders(IDictionary`2 env) in c:\local\identity\server3\AccessTokenValidation\source\AccessTokenValidation\Plumbing\ScopeRequirementMiddleware.cs:97
```

Should this be happening or is there something I have missed? app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll) is set in the startup.cs as specified in the getting started guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's indeed an issue here, but I'm not totally sure how to resolve it.

The [ScopeRequirementMiddleware](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/blob/master/source/AccessTokenValidation/Plumbing/ScopeRequirementMiddleware.cs#L83) tries to set the `Allow-Access-Control-Origin` header on the response, but it does so only if the scope requirement set in the middleware is not met.

This obviously conflicts with the fact that we already have the CORS middleware earlier in the OWIN pipeline which has already set this specific header.

I'm not sure why the scope requirement middleware sets these headers in this specific case, I'll create an issue on GitHub and link it back here for visibility.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I actually did create an issue here - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/issues/93 but with no reply. Apologies should have linked it in my initial post.